# C# XML Documentation file with Angular Brackets for Generic Method

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xml-documentation

I have a method like this in my class project (dll)

```
public T[] mkArray<T>(int n)
{
  return new T[n];
}
```

If I generate the XML file (when the DLL is build) for this, I get

```
<member name="M:Dynamo.DocumentationTestLibrary.TestDocumentation.mkArray``1(System.Int32)">
```

How to get rid of ``1 from the method name? I would like to get
M:Dynamo.DocumentationTestLibrary.TestDocumentation.mkArray[T].